# How can I have a base class with virtual functions which occupies 0 bytes in c++?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying to create an octree to contain data. Each piece of data contained in the octree is about 4 bytes. I have the following implementation.

```
struct p_CountResult
{
    unsigned int leaves;
    unsigned int nodes;
};

struct o_Parent
{
    o_Parent() 
    {
    }

    virtual void count(p_CountResult& _in) const
    {
    }
};

struct Leaf : o_Parent
{
    const Type_T data_;

    Leaf(const Type_T& _data, const unsigned char& _depth) : o_Parent(), data_(_data)
    {
    }

    void count(p_CountResult& _in) const override
    {
        _in.leaves += 1;
    }
};

struct Node : o_Parent
{
    o_Parent* children[8];
    
    Node(...) : o_Parent()
    {
        this->Subdivide(_depth, _targetDepth);
    }

    ~Node()
    {
        for (const auto& _c : children)
            delete _c;
    }

    void count(p_CountResult& _in) const override
    {
        _in.nodes += 1;
        for (const auto& child : children)
        {
            child->count(_in);
        }
    }
};
```

As you can see I created a base class which is o_Parent, which has just one virtual function for now (might also have more in the future), but has no data at all. The reason I need this baseclass is to use polymorphism on both the call of `count()` and to create an octree which can have a Node or a Leaf as a root:

```
template<typename Type_T>
struct Octree
{
     const o_Parent* root_;
}
```

But using this base class makes the size of the octree much bigger than it needs to (I think), as this are the results I obtain from profiling the different sizes of the classes.

```
unsigned char: 1
o_Parent: 4
Type_T: 4
Leaf: 8
Node: 36
```

As you can see the Type_T, which is the data type, is 4 bytes, but a leaf is 8 bytes, and this causes an octree to be almost twice as big as it would be if the Leaf was just 4 bytes, which is really the amount of data I need.

Is there a way to create an empty Base Class with virtual functions? By reading online I found that c++ doesn't allow size 0 classes because for example it wouldn't be able to allocate arrays of such classes. But if I understood correctly, I'm not doing so in my code as I'm allocating an array of pointers to such class in the Node superclass, so such restriction shouldn't apply (?)
Am I doing this in the correct way or is there a better way to do what I'm trying to achieve? I thing that something that could help is someway of telling the compiler that I am never instancing the class o_Parent by itself, so that it doesn't need to worry abot allocation size (something similar to Dart's `abstract`) but I haven't found a way of doing so in c++.

Comment: As soon as a base class introduces at least one `virtual` function, the compiler will automatically add a pointer to the virtual table inside the class. A pure virtual base class will therefore have a size of `sizeof(void*)`, which is 8 bytes on 64-bit platforms. So no, it is impossible to have a virtual base class of size 0.

Comment: @prapin It's not even possible to have a _non-virtual_ class, that occupies less than one byte.

Comment: Get rid of the leaf class, the inheritance, and the virtual counting and represent leaves with a null pointer.

Comment: @molbdnilo Thanks for the suggestion, that could be a good idea but how could I store the data which would be stored in the Type_T variable?